# How to prove $1^3+5^3+3^3=153,16^3+50^3+33^3=165033,166^3+500^3+333^3=166500333,\cdots$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I saw on facebook some image on which these identities that I am going to write below are labeled as "amazing math fact" and on the image there are these identities:

> $1^3+5^3+3^3=153$
>
> $16^3+50^3+33^3=165033$
>
> $166^3+500^3+333^3=166500333$
>
> $1666^3+5000^3+3333^3=166650003333$

and then it is written under these identities "and so on and on and on and on!" which suggests that for every $k \in \mathbb N$ we shuld have

> $(1 \cdot 10^k + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 6 \cdot 10^i)^3 + (5 \cdot 10^k)^3 + (\sum_{i=0}^{k} 3 \cdot 10^i)^3=16...650...03...3$

(on the right hand side of the above stated identity the number of times that number $6$ is shown up is $k-1$, the number of times that number $0$ is shown up is $k-1$ and the number of times that number $3$ is shown up is $k$)

This problem seems attackable with mathematical induction but I would like to see how it could be proved without using mathematical induction in any step(s) of the proof.

Comment: I would write it as $(\frac{10^n-4}6)^3+(5\cdot 10^{n-1})^3+27(\frac {10^n-1}9)^3$ and sort out the terms.

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((10%5En-4)%2F6)%5E3%2B(5*10%5E(n-1))%5E3%2B27*((10%5En-1)%2F9)%5E3) says it is $(100^n+2)(10^n-1)/6$

Comment: @RossMillikan I do not understand what is the advantage of writing it in that form?

Comment: It lets you manipulate the terms.  Now you can expand the cubes and get terms like $10^{3n}, 10^{2n}$ and so on.  You will be able to combine the like terms that come from the various pieces.

Comment: This is related to the fact that $\frac{1}{6^3}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}=\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh, so in that form I only need to take the cube of sum of two terms instead of sum of $k$ terms when it is written in the form in which I wrote it, right?

Comment: ... and re-expressing @RossMillikan's Alpha result, $(100^n+2)(10^n-1)/6 = ({10^n-4\over 6})10^{2n} + (\frac{10^n}2)10^n + \frac{10^n-1}{3}$, as desired

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I could ask this as a whole new question but maybe there is no need if you can answer me in the comment and the question is: Are there any known identities like this one for some power other than the cube?

Comment: Deleting this temporarily because it is apparently now in an ongoing contest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the three $n$-digit numbers
\begin{align}
a &= 16\ldots6 = \tfrac16 (10^n - 4), \\
b &= 50\ldots0 = \tfrac12 10^n, \\
c &= 33\ldots3 = \tfrac13 (10^n - 1). \\
\end{align}

Then
\begin{align}
a^3 + b^3 + c^3 &= \frac{1}{6^3} (10^n - 4)^3
                    + \frac{1}{2^3} (10^n)^3 + \frac{1}{3^3} (10^n - 1)^3.
\end{align}
Working out the major terms on the right-hand side,

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{6^3} (10^n - 4)^3
  &= \frac1{6^3}(10^{3n} - 3\cdot4\cdot 10^{2n}
      + 3\cdot4^2\cdot 10^n - 4^3) \\
  &= \frac{1}{216}10^{3n} - \frac{1}{18}10^{2n}
     + \frac{2}{9}10^n - \frac{8}{27}, \\[.7ex]
\frac{1}{3^3} (10^n - 1)^3
  &= \frac1{3^3}(10^{3n} - 3\cdot 10^{2n} + 3\cdot 10^n - 1) \\
  &= \frac{1}{27}10^{3n} - \frac{1}{9}10^{2n}
     + \frac{1}{9}10^n - \frac{1}{27}, \\[.7ex]
\frac{1}{6^3} (10^n - 4)^3 + \frac{1}{3^3} (10^n - 1)^3
  &= \left(\frac{1}{216} + \frac{1}{27}\right)10^{3n}
            - \left(\frac{1}{18} + \frac{1}{9}\right)10^{2n} \\
  & \qquad  + \left(\frac{2}{9} + \frac{1}{9}\right)10^n
            - \left(\frac{8}{27} + \frac{1}{27}\right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{24} 10^{3n} - \frac{1}{6} 10^{2n} 
       + \frac{1}{3}10^n - \frac{1}{3}, \\[.7ex]
\frac{1}{2^3} (10^n)^3 &= \frac{1}{8} 10^{3n}.
\end{align}

Then, since $\frac{1}{24} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{6}$,
\begin{align}
a^3 + b^3 + c^3 
&= \frac1{6^3} (10^n - 4)^3
     + \frac1{2^3} (10^n)^3 + \frac1{3^3} (10^n - 1)^3 \\
  &= \frac16 10^{3n} - \frac16 10^{2n} + \frac13 10^n - \frac13.
\end{align}
But
$$\frac16 10^{3n}
   = \overbrace{16\ldots6}^{\text{$3n$ digits}}.666\ldots.$$
Subtract
$$\frac16 10^{2n}
   = \overbrace{16\ldots6}^{\text{$2n$ digits}}.666\ldots$$
and the result is
$$\frac16 10^{3n} - \frac16 10^{2n}
   = \overbrace{16\ldots6}^{\text{$n$ digits}}\overbrace{50\ldots0}^{\text{$2n$ digits}}.$$

Continuing,
\begin{align}
\frac13 10^n &= \overbrace{33\ldots3}^{\text{$n$ digits}}.333\ldots, \\
\frac13      &= \phantom{33\ldots{}}0.333\ldots, \\
\frac13 10^n - \frac13 &= \overbrace{33\ldots3}^{\text{$n$ digits}}, \\
\frac16 10^{3n} - \frac16 10^{2n} + \frac13 10^n - \frac13
   &= \overbrace{16\ldots6}^{\text{$n$ digits}}\overbrace{50\ldots000\ldots0}^{\text{$2n$ digits}} \\
   & \phantom{=} + \phantom{6\ldots650\ldots0} \overbrace{33\ldots3}^{\text{$n$ digits}}  \\[1ex]
   &= \overbrace{16\ldots6}^{\text{$n$ digits}}\overbrace{50\ldots0}^{\text{$n$ digits}}\overbrace{33\ldots3}^{\text{$n$ digits}}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 14):

This deserves a shorter proof. Call $x=10^{k+1}$. Then we have:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}166\ldots 666&=&\frac{x}{6}-\frac{2}{3}\\500\ldots 000&=&\frac{x}{2}\\333\ldots 333&=&\frac{x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\end{array}$$

Now: the sum of the cubes on the left-hand side is:

$$\color{red}{166\ldots 666^3+500\ldots 000^3+333\ldots 333^3}=\left(\frac{x}{6}-\frac{2}{3}\right)^3+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^3+\left(\frac{x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=\frac{1}{6^3}((x-4)^3+(3x)^3+(2x-2)^3)=\frac{1}{6^3}(36x^3-36x^2+72x-72)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{6}(x^3-x^2+2x-2)}$$

On the other hand, the big number on the right-hand side is:

$$\color{red}{1666\ldots666\cdot x^2+500\ldots000\cdot x+333\ldots333}=\left(\frac{x}{6}-\frac{2}{3}\right)\cdot x^2+\frac{x}{2}\cdot x+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}(x^3-4x^2+3x^2+2x-2)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{6}(x^3-x^2+2x-2)}$$

which is the same value.

(Note how we used multiplication by $x^2$ and $x$ to "shift those big numbers to the left".)