# How to derive this sequence: $1^3+5^3+3^3=153,16^3+50^3+33^3=165033,166^3+500^3+333^3=166500333,\cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found it is interesting but I don't know how the R.H.S is coming from the L.H.S,
i.e, how to derive this sequence?
The sequence is as follows:
$$1^3+5^3+3^3=153$$
$$16^3+50^3+33^3=165033$$
$$166^3+500^3+333^3=166500333$$
$$1666^3+5000^3+3333^3=166650003333$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$\text{and so on}$$
So,any help please...

Comment: Small error : in the middle it is $50 , 500,5000$ and so on.

Comment: Sequence $A246057$ in OEIS is also funny ! Notice that your sequence was entered in year 2017.

Comment: If you write every term $a_k$ in the sequence as $a_k=\frac{b_k}{9}$, you should be able to get a closed fromula. Eg: 1666= 14994/9 = (15*(10^{n})-6) /9 ;
5000 = 5*10^{n} ; 3333*9 = 29997 = 30*(10^n) - 3 . And 166650003333 *9 = 1499850029997 = (150*(10^n) - 15) *(10^(2n+1)) + (30*(10^n) -3) . Then you just plug them in the formula and see if all the components match. It's tedious, but it works.

Comment: For the fun, in the OEIS window, just type **curious cubic identity**

Comment: **Duplicate** of  [How to prove this curiosity that has to do with cubes of certain numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646685/how-to-prove-this-curiosity-that-has-to-do-with-cubes-of-certain-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $n$th such equation is $$\left(\tfrac{5\times 10^{n-1}-2}{3}\right)^3+(5\times 10^{n-1})^3+\left(\tfrac{10^n-1}{3}\right)^3=10^{3n-1}+\tfrac{2}{3}(10^{n-1}-1)10^{2n}+5\times 10^{2n-1}+\tfrac{10^n-1}{3},$$or with $x=10^n$ we can write it as $$\left(\tfrac{x-4}{6}\right)^3+\left(\tfrac{x}{2}\right)^3+\left(\tfrac{x-1}{3}\right)^3=\tfrac{x^3}{10}+\tfrac{2}{3}\left(\tfrac{x}{10}-1\right)x^2+\tfrac{x^2}{2}+\tfrac{x-1}{3},$$which we can verify algebraically (both sides are $\tfrac{(x-1)(x^2+2)}{6}$).

Answer (score 3):

First some notations, let express the repunits $r_n=11\cdots 1=\dfrac{(10^n-1)}9$ in term of $k=10^n$

$\begin{cases} 
a_n&=16\cdots 6&=10^{n-1}+6\ r_{n-1}&=\frac{k-4}6\\
b_n&=50\cdots 0&=5\times 10^{n-1}&=\frac{k}2\\
c_n&=33\cdots 3&=3\,r_n&=\frac{k-1}3\end{cases}$

The sum of cubes

$f(n)=a_n^3+b_n^3+c_n^3=\left(\frac{k-4}6\right)^3+\left(\frac k2\right)^3+\left(\frac{k-1}3\right)^3=\dfrac{k^3-k^2+2k-2}6=\dfrac{(k-1)(k^2+2)}6$

Can be expressed like this:
$$\boxed{f(n)=\dfrac{(10^n-1)(10^{2n}+2)}{6}}$$

But we are interested in the non-factored expression:

$\begin{align}f(n)&=\dfrac{k^3-k^2+2k-2}6\\&=\dfrac{k^3-4k^2+3k^2+2k-2}6\\&=\left(\dfrac{k^2-4k^2}6\right)+\left(\dfrac {3k^2}6\right)+\left(\dfrac{2k-2}6\right)=k^2\,a_n+k\,b_n+c_n=\overline{a_nb_nc_n}\end{align}$

Where

$$\overline{a_nb_nc_n}=\underbrace{16\cdots 6}_{a_n\times 10^{2n}}\;\underbrace{50\cdots 0}_{b_n\times 10^n}\;\underbrace{33\cdots 3}_{c_n}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is sequence [A281857](http://oeis.org/search?q=153%2C165033&sort=&language=&go=Search) in OEIS. They give the recurrence relation
$$a_n = 1111\,a_{n-1} - 112110\,a_{n-2} + 1111000\,a_{n-3} - 1000000\,a_{n-4} $$ for which which you already found the first terms.